# Problems with CI4 filter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect, filter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to apply an 'Except' rule on all methods of my controller use, but it is not working; it's stucks in a loop "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS."

```
public $globals = [
    'before' => [
        'notAuth' => ['except' => 'auth/*'],
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'csrf',
        // 'invalidchars',
    ],
    'after' => [
        'toolbar',
        // 'honeypot',
        // 'secureheaders',
    ],
];
```

**Filters.php**

```
use App\Filters\Auth\NotAuthFilter;

public $aliases = [
    'csrf' => CSRF::class,
    'toolbar' => DebugToolbar::class,
    'honeypot' => Honeypot::class,
    'invalidchars' => InvalidChars::class,
    'secureheaders' => SecureHeaders::class,
    'notAuth' => NotAuthFilter::class,
];
```

**The filter**

```
class NotAuthFilter implements FilterInterface
{
    public function before(RequestInterface $request, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Verifica se o usuário possui uma sessão válida
        if (!session()->has('logged_in')) {
            return redirect()->to('auth?back='.uri_string());
        }
    }

    public function after(RequestInterface $request, 
        ResponseInterface $response, $arguments = null)
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: please show as well your `public $aliases ` array, specially the one entry for `notAuth` and the corresponding filter @ app\Filters\notAuth.php

Comment: @Vickel it's on edit 1.

Comment: what auth library do you use?, you'll need to call something like `if( !$ionAuth->getUserId()`... what is `session()->has('logged_in')` ?

Comment: No one, i just check if 'logged_in' parameter exists in session, if not exists, redirect user to auth page, but i need to ignore all methods from auth controller without expecifying page per page.

Comment: It's just checking if 'logged_in' attribute is set, i don't need the value, just if it's set or not